# How do I fix this jQuery conflict relating to scrolling?

Tags: jquery

It came up in another question that I have a jQuery conflict that is preventing my 'scroll to top' code from working.

I'm using Wordpress which loads jQuery 1.12.3 in no-conflict mode.

I have the following code which is used to scroll down from my post title and image to the actual content.

```
// Smooth scroll to content
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 50
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Then on the same page, I have the following code, that allows users to scroll to the top.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn(); 
        } else { 
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut(); 
        } 
    }); 
    $('.scrollup').click(function(){ 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Now if i remove the scroll to content code at the top, then the scroll to top code works fine, but with both them present on the page, only the former works.

When the 'scroll to top' code is present on the page, the browser gives the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$target.offset().top')`

Comment: Are these in the same JS file? If not, which one is first in the source order?

Comment: Yes they are in the same JS file and in the order shown.